# Where does the expoClientID go?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am adding Facebook login to my expo app and it says in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#facebook) to enter my `expoClientId` somewhere.

The problem is I cant figure out where to put it. Do I put it in my app.json? Maybe my package.json? In the Facebook developer portal somewhere? Maybe I put it in my expo console somewhere?

***Does anyone know where the `expoClientId` should live?*** The documentation doesn't say where to put it.

Edit: It looks like I also need to place an `iosClientId` and an `androidClientId` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's a part of the [FacebookAuthRequestConfig interface](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#facebookauthrequestconfig) which is used as `useAuthRequest()` parameter ([Expo src](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-auth-session/src/providers/Facebook.ts#L141)).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you pass it in the request to authorize with facebook like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Facebook from 'expo-auth-session/providers/facebook';
import { ResponseType } from 'expo-auth-session';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, FacebookAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp({
   /* Config */
});

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {
   const [request, response, promptAsync] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
     responseType: ResponseType.Token,
     clientId: <YOUR FBID>,
     expoClientId: <YOUR FBID>, //this is where you add them
     iosClientId: <YOUR FBID>, 
     androidClientId: <YOUR FBID>,
   });

   React.useEffect(() => {
     if (response?.type === 'success') {
        const { access_token } = response.params;
        const auth = getAuth();
        const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(access_token);
        // Sign in with the credential from the Facebook user.
        signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
      }
    }, [response]);

   return (
      <Button
        disabled={!request}
        title="Login"
        onPress={() => {
          promptAsync();}}
      />
   );
}
```