# What is expoClientId?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am implementing Google Authentication in Expo using the [official documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/google-authentication/). In their example, they use the following code block:

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
  androidClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  iosClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
});
```

However, when I try to use this code I get the error that: *Error: Client Id property `expoClientId` must be defined to use Google auth on this platform.*

Does anyone know what this `expoClientId` should be? I see another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388264/where-does-the-expoclientid-go), using Facebook, where the `expoClientId` is specified as `FBID`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#googleauthrequestconfig), `expoClientId` is necessary when using the Expo Go app as Expo will be acting as a proxy for your authentication request. It is **not** the same as the Android or iOS client ids.

To generate the `expoClientId` for Google authentication, do the following on Google Cloud Platform:

1. Create a new OAuth Client ID but set the type as `Web Application`.
2. Set `Authorized JavaScript origins` to `https://auth.expo.io`
3. Set `Authorized redirect URIs` to `https://auth.expo.io/@{username}/{SLUG}`. A complete example would be `https://auth.expo.io/@abundance/MyExampleProject`
4. Use the generated Client ID as the expo client id.

You must be logged into the expo cli, and the SLUG can be found in the `app.json` file.

Comment: Can you link the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much!

To add: The `expoClientId` needs to go into the `useAuthRequest`, next to `androidClientId` and `iosClientId`.

Comment: This worked exactly as expected!

Comment: @MichelH. LOL, Next question was this, where to put this expoClientId as this field is ignored in EXPO docs.

Answer (score -1):

after adding your android and ios client ids you can add your expo client id like so:

1. import { ResponseType } from "expo-auth-session"
2. expoClientId: "your expo client id",
   expoClientSecret: "your expo client secret",
   responseType: ResponseType.Token,
   scopes: ["profile", "email"],
3. where to get your expo client id? from your expo account