# expoClientId error using expo-react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-google-login

I am trying to develop an android app with google authentication managed by firebase using expo react native, I have the following error, any help would be greatly appreciated
I use Expo Go to do the tests

```
Error: Client Id property `expoClientId` must be defined to use Google auth on this platform.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
- ... 27 more stack frames from framework internals

Error: Client Id property `expoClientId` must be defined to use Google auth on this platform.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
- ... 7 more stack frames from framework internals
Error: Client Id property `expoClientId` must be defined to use Google auth on this platform.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
- ... 27 more stack frames from framework internals

Error: Client Id property `expoClientId` must be defined to use Google auth on this platform.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
- ... 7 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I attached the project at: https://github.com/carlobeni/React-Native-Expo-Login

The solution indicated in [What is expoClientId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839524/what-is-expoclientid) has not worked for me

Comment: Welcome! In the link you provided "What is expoClientId?" Try the second comment there in the answer. "To add: The expoClientId needs to go into the useAuthRequest, next to androidClientId and iosClientId"